# Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ssl, rvm

I just discovered I can no longer `gem push …` any more and some digging led me to a need to update my RVM SSL certs.

I ran `rvm osx-ssl-certs status all` but that gave me:

```
/Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': dlopen(/Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/openssl.bundle
    from /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/davesag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for : Old.
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

`rvm -v` shows I am running the latest RVM (as of today)

```
rvm 1.22.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Oddly I am not sure why it's referring to `ruby-2.0.0-p195` however as `rvm list` gives

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your questions mentions three paths `/opt/local`, `/usr/local` and `/etc/openssl` they belong to **Macports**, **Homebrew** and **SM Framework** respectively.

As the last one is used to build static rubies it is harmeless and not related to the problem. The other two suggest that you have switched from **macports** to **homebrew** between installing the rubies.

You need to reinstall `ruby-2.0.0-p195` which is referring still the old paths from **macports**, you can do it with:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p195
```

You can get more details about the rubies and openssl paths they use running:

```
rvm --debug osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up wiping out all the last relics from macports that were hanging about, upgrading rvm, uninstalling ruby-2.0.0-p195 and reinstalling ruby-2.0.0-p247 and it seems happy now.

Comment: Note that the version of ruby here is outdated.

Answer (score 116):

Uninstalling openssl and re-installing it worked for me.

```
brew remove openssl
```

and then

```
brew install openssl
```

Comment: Also worked for me (and I went as far as imploding and reinstalling rvm). Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading to Mavricks broke openssl for me. This fixed it.

Comment: Also worked for for me as well!  Same issue... Mavericks broke `openssl`, your advice fixed it!

Comment: Switched Macbooks at work and going through Mac's migration software, it broke openssl for me. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Issues related to Mavericks new install seem to be addressed by reinstalling openssl. In my case, after restore from time machine.

Comment: removing and then installing fresh worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't `brew reinstall openssl` do the same?

Answer (score 13):

Trying to run 'bundle' I also started getting the openssl dylib complaint, though a slightly different path.
I tried most of these, and a few other things. I had rvm, and some broken remnants of a fink install, though I'd tried to replace it with brew a while back.
Many times I was getting

```
Library not loaded: /sw/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

However trying to re-install openssl with brew always produced

```
sudo brew link openssl
Warning: openssl is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

or

```
Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
```

So it was pretty confusing what I should do. What seemed to help in the end, after much trial, included:

```
$ rm /Users/dan/.rvm/rubies/default/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/openssl.bundle
```

which had references to the non-existent /sw/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib file.
Then

```
$ sudo brew update && sudo brew upgrade
$ rvm reset
```

brought my version up from 1.9.1 to

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

At which point I had to re-install bundler (?)

```
$ gem install bundler
```

But finally I could run 'bundle' on my project and it seemed to behave.

Comment: I had a similar issue recently with rbenv and just had to do:

`rm /Users/Jeff/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle`

and then:
`rbenv install 2.6.6`

Answer (score 8):

> Homebrew changed its version of Openssl to 1.1 days ago
> (Homebrew/homebrew-core@0349a7c 25 and Homebrew/homebrew-core@b4b9c1c
> 10). We can downgrade Openssl to the older version to temporarily fix
> this issue while waiting for the new rebuild to come (or do it
> manually):

So I solved like this:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/30fd2b68feb458656c2da2b91e577960b11c42f4/Formula/openssl.rb
```

**UPDATE**

From catalina you could get a message like:

> Error: Calling Installation of openssl from a GitHub commit URL is disabled!

In this case I recomend you to go to the URL and download the content into a file (with name openssl.rb). Then you can do:

```
brew install openssl.rb
```

Comment: After brew update, this error happened for me, this solved the issue

Comment: @muhammedcelik  I am on Xcode 12.1 , macOS Bigsur
 I am just trying to update pods for my project , the above solution din worked what ekzactly u did?

Answer (score 6):

All the versions of rubies were working for me and I got a project on ruby 2.6.5. then I got this `library not found` error for openssl. To solve that, I did

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install openssl
```

Then all the other versions stop working because it `library not found` for open ssl. Since I am using chruby for ruby version manager, I remove the version folder and reinstall them and it works.

Tl;dr update and upgrade brew, install openssl and reinstall ruby version

Comment: Thanks! definitely helped solve my issue which involved 'uwsgi', so i had to add `brew reinstall uwsgi` & `brew link --overwrite uwsgi`, my full solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274385/2298002

Answer (score 4):

rbenv user here, tried a couple of the solutions above but nothing worked until I uninstalled the version of ruby I had and reinstalled. 
So:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.4.3
rbenv install 2.4.3
```

fixed my issue and I was able to bundle.

Comment: `rbenv install <version>` and selecting `y` is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the Ruby version when bundling:

I did:

```
rvm list
```

output:

```
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
```

and then I changed to `ruby-2.0.0-p451`:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p451
```

and:

```
bundle
```

bundle was done successfully ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the postgres gem `pg` and found this issue: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/322

This is what I did to fix it:

```
brew reinstall postgresql
```

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one @JunjiZhi

Answer (score -1):

In my case an update with ReactJS + Node env screwed one rails project and after expending a lot of time either reinstalling ruby version via `rbenv` (was 2.5.1 BTW) and also reinstall `openssl` via `homebrew`, bundler reinstall (none of these worked) a simple

`brew update && brew upgrade`

did the trick!

was running `OSX` and `mojave`

Answer (score -11):

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

worked for me

Comment: Never run brew with sudo ! Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: Brew strongly recommends not to use sudo with it as it can harm the system

Comment: i don't think brew will allow you to run as `sudo`, it alway stops me