# uWSGI can not load libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, uwsgi, libssl

When I call `uwsgi`, it always shows the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xingshi/anaconda/bin/uwsgi
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Here is all the libssl.1.0.0.dylib on my Mac:

```
$ locate libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Users/xingshi/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/Users/xingshi/anaconda/pkgs/openssl-1.0.1c-0/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

And my `uwsgi` is in `anaconda`

```
$which uwsgi
/Users/xingshi/anaconda/bin/uwsgi
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

MacPorts usually install softwares into `/opt/local/`, but brew will install softwares into `/usr/local/`. It seems that my `uwsgi` is looking for the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` in /usr/local/lib, so I use brew to install openssl and relink it:

```
brew install --upgrade openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Comment: This seems to have solved [a related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31406148/656912) for me. Will it be safe to do this every time I run `brew upgrade --all` as part of my regular Homebrew/Python maintenance?

Comment: thanks ! this command `brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force` worked!

Comment: What if this error happens when we want to install Homebrew? [Like this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564036/error-when-installing-homebrew-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libssl-1-0-0-dy)

Comment: getting multiple errors: 
--upgrade is not an option

Comment: Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1

Answer (score 9):

I performed this:

I have been having this error for a long time and performing

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl
```

did not work for me even including "--force"

However, I found this link to this blog and it did work for me.

http://mithun.co/hacks/library-not-loaded-libcrypto-1-0-0-dylib-issue-in-mac/

> > Step 1: Install openssl using brew
> >
> > ```
> > brew install openssl
> > ```
> >
> > Step 2: Copy copy libssl.1.0.0.dylib and
> >     libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
> >
> > ```
> > cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib  
> >
> > sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
> > ```
> >
> > Note the bold folder name. There will be change in that depending on
> >     your openssl version
> >
> > Step 3: Remove the existing links
> >
> > > ```
> > > sudo rm libssl.dylib libcrypto.dylib 
> > >
> > > sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib 
> > >
> > > sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib
> > > ```

I hope this helps!

Comment: be careful, I did that and it made things worse. I also tried copying the version from the anaconda path, that didn't work either.

Comment: After an eight hour adventure, this worked for me. I did not do step 3, and do not consider this a "final" solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

my error specifically for Mac OSx, was..

```
user-MacBook-Pro:src user$ uwsgi --enable-threads --ini deploy.ini
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
user-MacBook-Pro:src user$
```

this suddenly started happening, either after upgrading Mac OSx to v10.14.6 or after an extensive installation process playing around with aircrack-ng (i'm not sure which)

but, the following fixed my issue... (help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055043/2298002)

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install openssl # yielded 'already installed'
$ brew reinstall uwsgi # yielded 'could not symlink' error
$ brew link --overwrite uwsgi
```

NOTE: uwsgi now works fine, but i still cannot run `$ man uwsgi`, yields...

```
user-MacBook-Pro:src user$ man uwsgi
No manual entry for uwsgi
user-MacBook-Pro:src user$
```

... anyone have any incites to this?