# Error with MySQLdb on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip, mysql-python

I tried importing the MySQLdb within iPython and received the following error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f5538763dbdb> in <module>()
----> 1 import MySQLdb as mdb
      2 import sys

/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in <module>()
     17 from MySQLdb.release import __version__, version_info, __author__
     18 
---> 19 import _mysql
     20 
     21 if version_info != _mysql.version_info:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I found a few posts on Stackoverflow of a similar nature, where it was suggested that the System Integrity Protection should be disabled, which I have now.

I also edited my bashprofile as suggested for OSX El Capitan in this post, [Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) but I still haven't been able to overcome this issue.

A little more information incase it helps diagnose the issue:

- Python version: Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 
  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
- Result of 'which python' : /Users/user1/anaconda/bin/python
- MySQL Version installed: mysql-5.7.10
- MySQL-Python version: MySQL-python-1.2.5

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

Comment: I edited my bash profile as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264574/import-psycopg2-library-not-loaded-libssl-1-0-0-dylib, but still no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I figured that the issue might have been due to OpenSSL, and permissions related to this in El Capitan.
I found two resources which hinted at similar solutions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945292/2762934
2. https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/607

So here it is:

```
brew install --upgrade openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

Comment: `Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl`

Answer (score 5):

you can try:

```
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
helped for me

Comment: after trying a number of other suggestions to solve this issue whilst trying to get django to work with mysql on os x, this worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a few things including the brew install, unlink, link solution without any luck.  For OS X 10.12.3 running Python 2.7.12, Anaconda 2.3.0 the following worked for me.

1. Turn off System Integrity Protection: Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R, open the terminal and enter: csrutil disable; reboot
2. After rebooting: 
   cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib
   sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/