# Error when installing Homebrew: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on my MacOS (macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3)

And I keep getting the following error (the exact message I see in my terminal):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/[my_machine_name]/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I see a lot of solutions mentioning some *brew* related commands as part of their solution, but I'm trying to install brew here so I don't have brew yet. I'm wondering what I need to do?

**Edit:**

I'm using the following command to install brew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by installing libssh2 via conda environment manager.

```
conda install libssh2
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured what the problem was. The dylib couldn't be found. So I added the following line to the `~/.bash_profile` (you can open this file using the `nano ~/.bash_profile` command or open it using any other editor than `nano`):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib
```

This line simply tells where we should be looking for the dylibs. Just figure out where your dylibs are (in my case they are at `/opt/local/lib`) and add the path to the `~/.bash_profile` file.)

> **Notice:** This solution might potentially affect some other functionalities. But in my case, it helped to successfully install the Homebrew. It would be great if anyone shares a better solution if there's any.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to python 3.7 with conda.
New git repos would produce the following error with git pull or git push

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Users/alexis/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
>
> Reason: no suitable image found.

I'm on macOS 10.12.6 Sierra.
Reinstalling libssl or git, updating brew did not fix it.

The fix was

> conda update --prefix /Users//anaconda3 anaconda

I am now on

> conda 4.6.9