# Trouble with installing cocoapods: Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, cocoapods, homebrew

I'm installing cocoapods like this `sudo gem install cocoapods` which gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)     
dlopen(/Users/pepa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle, 9):
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib  
Referenced from: /Users/pepa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle 
Reason: image not found - /Users/pepa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/openssl.bundle 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

and sure enough this is empty:

```
ls: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib: No such file or directory
```

I've installed openssl using `brew`

```
brew list
autoconf        freetype        jansson         libgpg-error        libusb          openssl@1.1     readline        zlib
automake        gcal            jemalloc        libimobiledevice    libusbmuxd      p7zip           ruby
boost           gdbm            jpeg            libksba         libxml2         pcre            ruby-build
c-ares          gettext         libde265        libplist        libyaml         pkg-config      sphinx-doc
carthage        icu4c           libev           libpng          libzip          python@2        sqlite
coreutils       ideviceinstaller    libevent        libtasn1        lynx            python@3.9      usbmuxd
curl            ios-deploy      libffi          libtool         nghttp2         rbenv           xz
```

It's however possible that historically I've used MacPorts or even custom build.

I've tried most troubleshooting hints, e.g. from here: [uWSGI can not load libssl.1.0.0.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944770/uwsgi-can-not-load-libssl-1-0-0-dylib)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the library elsewhere on the system, copied it and it works.
I'm not proud of it but it works.

```
cp /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
cp /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```