# Can't Update Ruby or Install Gems

Tags: ruby

when i try to `gem update --system` or `gem install "gem"` I get this error...

```
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
dlopen(/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/openssl.bundle
Reason: image not found - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Tried reinstalling everything, none of that stuff worked.
What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

**comment**(I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation to write it in comment form)

That question might be what you are looking for.
[ruby - Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168842/library-not-loaded-opt-local-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-loaderror)