# MySQL python setup error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I am following https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm to connect Python with SQL.

```
gunzip MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar
cd MySQL-python-1.2.2
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

The last command "python setup.py install" gives :

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth'

Answer (score 1):

Using Anaconda, you should use `conda install <package-name>`

**Linux / Windows:** `conda install mysql-python`

**Mac OS:** `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/coursera mysql-python`

Then it will check for dependencies and install them for you.

Comment: Does not work. conda install mysql-python
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - mysql-python

Comment: OK. That was the Linux version. I'll get the OSX setup for you.

Comment: Updated with Mac OS instructions. Verified working in Python 2.7 Anaconda

Comment: Uprooted but not verified. Thanks a lot. I trust your solution is right, but it did not work for me. I can install it now with OSX terminal, but cannot import it in Python. ERROR MESSAGE:   import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Looks like an openssl error now. Try the following links that seem to address this part of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19172859/3006366   and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20946142/3006366  (Both separate answers to the same post)