# why does bundle install and Gem install bundler give me an openssl error when openssl is already installed?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am having a problem where neither bundle install nor gem install bundler is working giving me the following problems:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.1) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
/Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/security.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:65:in `run'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:224:in `block in install'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:136:in `temporary'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:223:in `install'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/bundle:3:in `load'
    from ./bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

and when running gem install bundler

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/tuanperera/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin17/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have already tried to reinstall openssl as well as ruby and rvm and nothing has worked so far and as such would really appreciate if anyone would know how to fix this.
Cheers

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168842/library-not-loaded-opt-local-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-loaderror?

Comment: yes managed to fix it thanks!

Comment: Can you respond to the question with resolution or link to it and mark it as answered please? So others can benefit from it if they find your question.

Comment: oh sorry but yea it was that post that led me to the fix!