# ROR Image not Found - openssl.bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

```
 $ bundle update
Traceback (most recent call last):
    33: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    32: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    31: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
    30: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
    29: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    27: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
    26: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    25: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
    24: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    23: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    22: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:303:in `update'
    21: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/settings.rb:124:in `temporary'
    20: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `block in update'
    19: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/update.rb:52:in `run'
    18: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    17: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    16: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/fetcher.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/fetcher.rb:11:in `<module:Bundler>'
    14: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/fetcher.rb:221:in `<class:Fetcher>'
    13: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    12: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    11: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/fetcher/index.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     9: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     8: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     6: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     5: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/s3_uri_signer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     2: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': dlopen(/Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86
```

Ruby 2.5.1p57
Rails 5.1.2

I have upgraded Ruby to 2.7.1, but that broke the application. I uninstalled and reinstalled ruby 2.5.1 and openssl.
Why am I unable to run the most basic command?

Comment: Of the following two files, which exist? `dlopen(/Users/snowflake/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)`

Comment: libssl.1.0.0.dylib is missing
but i did find it /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0.2t/1.0.2t/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Comment: Looks like you moved your `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` since installing ruby. (perhaps you switched from MacPorts to Homebrew) Try re-installing ruby.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168842/library-not-loaded-opt-local-lib-libssl-1-0-0-dylib-loaderror)